# One hibiscus plant is experiencing delayed leafing

Tags: diagnosis, hibiscus

Hi I have got 4 Hibiscus plants/trees in my garden all in relative same type/ spots. (South facing against a fence) three are in good condition but one (in the middle) has only just started to leaf. The others have started to leaf a month or two ago! Last year this same plant had very few flowers! Would appreciate any ideas whether this is a bug or disease! [image]

Comment: Welcome to the group!  Some closeup pictures would be helpful especially if you suspect a disease.  Also, are there any differences (e.g plants growing next to them) that would indicate why one is behaving differently from others?  Please update the question with more details

Comment: @JStorage This is a reminder that it takes 10 rep to post more than two pictures. If Andy doesn't get that much rep, it would help if you could pick what you think would be the most important second picture, and have him post that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try Nitrogen based fertilizer. Nitrogen promotes healthy foliage. Once the plant has leaves, give phosphorous fertilizer which enhances root systems and flower production.